# How to get database stuff by using customized connection

Tags: codeigniter-3

I want to auto save the sql query every time, I found this [article](http://jigarjain.com/blog/saving-all-db-queries-in-codeigniter/), if I do everything by the page it will work, but the problem is, I have master and slave database, therefore I have to connect to database like:

**model/Users.php**

```
<?php

class Users extends CI_Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';

    public $master;
    public $slave;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->master = $this->load->database('master', true);
        $this->slave = $this->load->database('slave', true);
    }

    public function save($datas)
    {
        $this->master->insert($this->table, $datas);

        return $this->master;
    }
}
```

Then I adjust demo code like:

```
<?php

class Query_log
{
    public function log_query()
    {
        $ci =& get_instance();

        $filepath = APPPATH . 'logs/Query-log-' . date('Y-m-d') . '.php';
        $handle = fopen($filepath, "a+");

        $times = $ci->master->query_times;

        foreach ($ci->master->queries as $key => $query) {
            $sql = $query . " \n Execution Time:" . $times[$key];
            fwrite($handle, $sql . "\n\n");
        }

        fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

Of course I got error message

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Users::$master

Filename: hooks/query_log.php
```

How to make it right?

Comment: Where comes `Chen` from?

Comment: In code, what is `Chan::$master`? I can't see any php class named Chan in code you provided.

Comment: It's typo, I fixed it